# Why is iOS 16/Xcode 14 causing UI responsiveness issues for apps that use location services and adMob?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, core-location, ios16

I get this error:

> This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.

Before iOS 16 UI was fine, now it indeed seems laggy.

Apparently it is linked to AdMob. Google says it is a bug with Apple. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467

Worst part is that in testing I actually think it does cause UI `Unresponsiveness`. I really don't think waiting for an update is a good solution.

Have any of you had this and done something to fix it?

This is how my code looks:

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    let authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
    } else {
        authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
    case .notDetermined:
    case .restricted:
    case .denied:
    @unknown default:
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }
```

Comment: What is the connection between Google and [the post hyperlinked](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is showing because you are calling the **CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()** in the main thread, you are already checking with **locationManager.authorizationStatus** if the location services are enabled, if you need to perform some action with the location services enabled you can do it in the **case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:**

```
     let authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
    } else {
        authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
    // your code here
    case .notDetermined:
    case .restricted:
    case .denied:
    @unknown default:
        print("Location services are not enabled")
```